# Maximum Likelihood Estimation on Exponential Family

Tags: maximum-likelihood, exponential-family

Does any one know of a good source for the study of maximum likelihood estimation on a general exponential family of the form $f(x;\theta)=a(\theta)g(x)\exp[{\sum_{i=1}^{k} b_i(\theta)R_i(x)}]$? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Off the top of my head, Jun Shao's [Mathematical Statistics](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Statistics-Springer-Texts/dp/0387953825) and Lehmann and Casella's [Theory of Point Estimation](https://www.amazon.com/Theory-Point-Estimation-Springer-Statistics/dp/0387985026/) both discuss this, but I don't know if there is a canonical one

Comment: @Chaconne. I also came to know about Jun Shao and Lehmann's other books as well. Very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The references in Chaconne's comment are both good textbooks. The [lecture notes](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnms/1215466757) by Larry Brown are also a common entry point into the literature.

Comment: Thank you @Lucas Roberts. These lecture notes seem very rigorous and I was expecting such a source.

Comment: @Ashok, glad you found them useful. If my answer satisfies your question please mark the answer correct.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot do so :)

Comment: @Ashok, no worries. I'm not sure if the community tracks the answered but unchecked posts but they might. It is easy to forget-I come across my own questions I forgot to mark answers correct too :) .